# Can you level with pvp in world of warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If yes, is it slower than regular questing?

Comment: Yes you can :D Blizz have made it very possible to do so and you get about 3 bars per win at lvl 89 :O Good leveling and fun too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can - it's perfectly possible to level from PvP. You will get experience from many activities from getting kills to capturing flags but the main source of experience will be from winning. This is especially the case when you're doing a 'Call to Arms' battleground as the experience bonus from winning a call to arms battleground will normally result in a full level or more at low level, and a large portion of a level at high level. This does mean however that queuing for specific battlegrounds will not result in the experience bonuses.

Regarding the speed of experience gain, yes - it is overall slower than questing, since you spend a period of time waiting for the queues and you're not guaranteed a win but if you end up with multiple wins in a row you will gain more experience than any other method of levelling during that period.

Your best bet is to do a mixture of questing while queuing for battlegrounds, although replacing dungeons with battlegrounds is generally more consistent in terms of experience gained.

Comment: What's the rules on Call to Arms? Is it a daily?

Comment: Not sure - I don't play anymore. I think CTA is weekends (fri-mon) but queuing for a random will still give you an experience bonus

Comment: @RavenDreamer - What do you mean "What are the rules" exactly?  The current CTA is clearly indicated within the game.

Comment: @Ramhound I meant in terms of repeatability. If you can gain nearly a full level for winning a match, I was curious (as an ex-WoW player myself) how often you could trigger that.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Alterac Valley gives a lot of experience points and honor when your team wins. I've leveled quite a few characters in that battleground during call to arms.

Comment: Additional information: since [patch 5.2](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/8226552/Patch_52_PTR_and_Patch_Notes_-_February_25-2_25_2013#pvp), players in low level battlegrounds are temporarily set to the maximum-level of the bracket, and gain stats accordingly. So pvp in the low levels of the bracket won't be as hard as they used to be.